# Why not move to second it block even use the before() hook in cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, mocha.js

I am using befor hook for login to the site then I am initiate the test cases so my problem is after the  execute before hook then first it block run and after run first it block then screen set to default blank page and didn't excecute the second it block.

I was writing a code within the describe first before hook then two it block and try to intiate befor hook above the describe but it didn't work. I need to login once then execute the other all test cases.

```
describe('VerifyLoginFunctionality',() => {

    const dashbord = new Dashboard()
    const loginpage = new LoginPage()
    const createtask = new Createtask()

    before (() => {
    cy.viewport(1280,800) // mackbook

    cy.fixture('example').then(function(data)
    {
        // use "This" keyword to access globaly for example.json file
    this.data1=data
    
        
    cy.wait(2000)
    // cy.visit("https://app-redesign.taskbuddy.se")
    
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('login_url'))


    //Verify the title of the page
    cy.title().should('eq',this.data1.Pagetitle)

    
    loginpage.SigninMannuallyButton().click()
    loginpage.TeamSpace().type(this.data1.TeamspaceName)

    loginpage.NextButton().click()
    loginpage.Email().type(this.data1.email)

    loginpage.Password().type(this.data1.Password)

    loginpage.SigninButton().click()

    cy.wait(3000)

        
        })
    
        })
    
        it('Verify the user profile',() => {
        
            dashbord.UserProfileButton().click()
            cy.wait(2000)
            dashbord.UserProfilePopupMiddleLayer().should('be.visible')


            dashbord.Firstname()
                .invoke('val')  // for input or textarea, .invoke('val')
                .then(text => {
                    const someText = text;
                    cy.log("aaa> "+someText)
                    // BDD style
                        expect(someText).to.equal("Toyota")

                        //TDD style
                        assert.equal(someText,"Toyota")
                })
        
                cy.wait(3000)

                dashbord.Givenname().clear()
                dashbord.Givenname().type("jjjjjjj")
                dashbord.Firstname().should('have.value',"jjjjjjj")
                cy.wait(1500)
                dashbord.CloseIconOnProfile().click()
                
                
        })
       

        it('Verify the create task',() => {
           // const dashbord = new Dashbord()

           createtask.CreateNewTaskButton().click()
               

        })
```

Comment: `before` should only be used to execute some code in preparation of the tests to come, you should'nt write any assertion inside it

Answer (score 3):

One way to do that is to set `testIsolation: false` in the `cypress.config.js` file.

But it's not best practice, you may cause false positive outcomes in 2nd, 3rd tests if state bleeds over the test boundary.

Better practice is to use `cy.session()` to cache the login. It only calls the login once, but is called in a `beforeEach()` to allow the cache to re-instate credentials for each and every test.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('login', () => {

    // login code here, is only ever called once!

    cy.visit(Cypress.env('login_url'))
    cy.title().should('eq',this.data1.Pagetitle)
    loginpage.SigninMannuallyButton().click()
    loginpage.TeamSpace().type(this.data1.TeamspaceName)  
    ... complete login code
  })
})

it('test1', () => {
  // is logged in
})

it('test2', () => {
  // is logged in
})

it('test3', () => {
  // is logged in
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

I have tried the above solution. it login in once but did not execute the second it block. Is it call session within it block?